# Copy to clipboard is not a function when copying text inside h3 tag

Tags: javascript, copy, clipboard

I'm trying to copy text to clipboard that is inside a h3 tag. I get the following error at the copyText.select() code line.

*Uncaught TypeError: copyText.select is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.*

edit: When using on a input-tag the copy to clipboard function works, but not when inside h3 tag.

#### HTML

```
<div class="colorDiv" id="firstColorObject">
    <h3 class="colorCode" id="p1" value="123">#Color 1</h3>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
document.querySelector("#firstColorObject").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var copyText = document.getElementById("p1");

    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);

}, false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call [select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) with an `<input>`-element but not with a `<h3>`-element.

Nevertheless you can take advantage of `<input>` when you assign the content of `#p1` to a hidden field before calling `select` with it.

**Note that:** Calling `select` with an hidden field only works when you wrap an actually visible field around a `<div>`-element that is hidden (only tested with `opacity:0`). A value could not be copied (through `select` and `document.execCommand("copy")`) from a truly hidden input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="copyText"/>
```

Hope my example below helps you (to execute it click on `"Run Code snippet"`-Button):

```js
document.querySelector("#firstColorObject").addEventListener("click", function(){

    var p1 = document.getElementById("p1");
    
    // set "#Color 1" with the hidden field so that you can call select on it
    var hiddenField = document.getElementById("copyText");
    hiddenField.value = p1.innerHTML;
    hiddenField.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    
    alert("Copied the text: " + hiddenField.value);

}, false);
```

```html
<div class="colorDiv" id="firstColorObject">
    <h3 class="colorCode" id="p1" value="123">#Color 1</h3>
    <div style="opacity:0">
        <input type="text" id="copyText"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh ye this would work for sure! Thanks! Any reason why h3 doesn't work by it self?

Comment: You are welcome. select is not supported with a h3-element because js is not implemented in browsers that way......h and input elements differ too much in the DOM-perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The [input.select()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) function is not applicable to `h3` . Manipulating the selection is usually done
with [window.getSelection().addRange()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/addRange#Examples) .

Try

```
<html>
<body>
<h3>Hello world</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
var h3 = document.querySelector('h3');
var r = document.createRange();
r.selectNode(h3);
window.getSelection().addRange(r);
document.execCommand("copy");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Clipboard](https://clipboardjs.com/)  js will be helpfull in your case